# os.system() execute command under which linux shell?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am using `/bin/tcsh` as my default shell.

However, the tcsh style command `os.system('setenv VAR val')` doesn't work for me. But `os.system('export VAR=val')` works.

So my question is how can I know the `os.system()` run command under which shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.system()` just calls the `system()` system call ("`man 3 system`"). On most *nixes this means you get `/bin/sh`.

Note that `export VAR=val` is technically not standard syntax (though `bash` understands it, and I think `ksh` does too). It will not work on systems where `/bin/sh` is actually the Bourne shell. On those systems you need to export and set as separate commands. (This will work with `bash` too.)

Comment: Confirm this behavior. So the `os.system()` is no longer useful. I am running some scripts that require bash, and this os.system is giving me hard time. 
So in the future I will always use the `subprocess`  : `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True,  executable="/bin/bash")`

Answer (score 11):

Was just reading [Executing BASH from Python](http://www.rubyops.net/executing-bash-from-python), then [17.1. subprocess — Subprocess management — Python v2.7.3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), and I saw the `executable` argument; and it seems to work:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:16:52) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.popen("echo $0").read()
sh
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.call("echo $0", shell=True).read()
/bin/sh
>>> print subprocess.Popen("echo $0", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
/bin/sh
>>> print subprocess.Popen("echo $0", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash").stdout.read()
/bin/bash
>>> print subprocess.Popen("cat <(echo TEST)", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>>> print subprocess.Popen("cat <(echo TEST)", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash").stdout.read()
TEST
```

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: I am that someone. This is what I was looking for. Thank you for noting this :)

Comment: Yes, this is so true when one is piping stdout from a single command to multiple commands using tee, something like `command out=stdout | tee >(command_1 in=stdin) >(command_2 in=stdin)`. Thanks for posting this, thumbs up~

Answer (score 9):

These days you should be using the [Subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system()`. According to the documentation there, the default shell is `/bin/sh`. I believe that `os.system()` works the same way.

Edit: I should also mention that the subprocess module allows you to set the environment available to the executing process through the `env` parameter.

Comment: Indeed, /bin/sh (which is almost always some form of bourne shell) is almost always what is meant when anything *nix-related says "the shell" without qualification. It may also be useful to note that if you really need to execute some snippet under a specific non-bourne shell, you could pass the function something like '/path/to/tcsh -c "your tcsh snippet here"'.

Answer (score 2):

If your command is a shell file, and the file is executable, and the file begins with "#!", you can pick your shell.

```
#!/bin/zsh
Do Some Stuff
```

You can write this file and then execute it with `subprocess.Popen(filename,shell=True)` and you'll be able to use any shell you want.

Also, be sure to read [this](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) about `os.system` and `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: i was going to point out that shell=True is not necessary, but then it occurred to me: is it the the shell that's responsible for interpreting shebangs and acting accordingly?

Comment: Correct.  The shell interprets the "magic" bytes "#!" to see what other shell should really be using this file.