# Problems running terminal command via Python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm working on a small project where I need to control a console player via python. This example command works perfectly on the Linux terminal:

```
mplayer -loop 0 -playlist <(find "/mnt/music/soundtrack" -type f | egrep -i '(\.mp3|\.wav|\.flac|\.ogg|\.avi|\.flv|\.mpeg|\.mpg)'| sort)
```

In Python I'm doing the following:

```
command = """mplayer -loop 0 -playlist <(find "/mnt/music/soundtrack" -type f | egrep -i '(\.mp3|\.wav|\.flac|\.ogg|\.avi|\.flv|\.mpeg|\.mpg)'| sort)""" 
os.system(command)
```

The problem is when I try it using Python it gives me an error when I run it:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm really confused here because it is the exact same string. Why doesn't the second method work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default user shell is probably `bash`. Python's `os.system` command calls `sh` by default in linux.

A workaround is to use `subprocess.check_call()` and pass [`shell=True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) as an argument to tell `subprocess` to execute using your default user shell.

```
import subprocess
command = """mplayer -loop 0 -playlist <(find "/mnt/music/soundtrack" -type f | egrep -i '(\.mp3|\.wav|\.flac|\.ogg|\.avi|\.flv|\.mpeg|\.mpg)'| sort)"""
subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested however a different error is occurring: `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` with a traceback `...returned non-zero exit status 2`. Also tried this `subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` but I get `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. Tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to be working...

Comment: A non-zero exit normally indicates a command failed in Linux. I would check the `mplayer` documentation to find out what the error is (if any).

Comment: Ok, I'm sure I'll get this working soon enough. At least I now know _why_ it isn't working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your python call 'os.system' is probably just using a different shell than the one you're using on the terminal:
**[os.system() execute command under which linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905221/os-system-execute-command-under-which-linux-shell)**

The shell you've spawned with os.system may not support parentheses for substitution.

Comment: He's using `<(...)` for process substitution, not grouping.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I just learned something new. Here's an explanation for anyone else who wants it:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution

Answer (score 0):

```py
import subprocess  
 
COMND=subprocess.Popen('command',shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
COMND_bytes = COMND.stdout.read() + COMND.stderr.read()  
print(COMND_bytes)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Right now it is unclear why this works while the original code doesn't