# Syntax error from the shell on a command being passed to os.system

Tags: python, shell

I have some odd behaviour occurring in my Python program.

```
perf_join_cmd = "join <(sort -k1,1 {}) <(sort -k1,1 {}) > {}.ScoreProfile"
perf_join_cmd = perf_join_cmd.format(meta, extracted_snps, out)
os.system(perf_join_cmd)
```

I am creating a string, passing in arguments to the string. The string represents a join/sort piped command to be ran on the shell, hence my call to os.system.

The error is:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `join <(sort -k1,1 ../../ADHD_GWAS.tbl) <(sort -k1,1 ../adhd-c/bin/adhd-merged.subset) > adhd-c.ScoreProfile'
```

I've been hacking away at this for long enough and I don't see anything that looks like a syntax error - so I suspect there's something deeper happening here and I was hoping someone could shed some light.

As an FYI, this is the output of the perf_jon_cmd when printed:

```
join <(sort -k1,1 ../../ADHD_GWAS.tbl) <(sort -k1,1 ../adhd-c/bin/adhd-merged.subset) > adhd-c.ScoreProfile
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try debugging this in bash first before running it through python?

Comment: Yes. Running the exact command in bash (just copying it from the print) runs fine.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584124/problems-running-terminal-command-via-python

Comment: Ah, so doing `os.system(perf_join_cmd, shell=True)` should solve it?

Comment: I myself don't know. I just googled the error and that was the first result.

Comment: I think that's the problem. I'm using substitution here - is there any way I can get system to use bash? Or will I need to swap to using subprocess instead?

Comment: Hm, not sure. The solution here suggests using `/bin/bash -c`, can you try that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822054/how-to-force-os-system-to-use-bash-instead-of-shell

Comment: Yep, that works! Feel free to leave an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: Oh awesome! Well, I see you already marked an answer and that one's a little more detailed, so I'll let him keep his points(though I think he has plenty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> ```

The `sh:` at the start indicates that the command was executed by `/bin/sh`,
and it is *not* Bash.
The `<(...)` syntax is not supported in `/bin/sh`.

You can try to run through Bash, just be careful with the quoting:

```
perf_join_cmd = "join <(sort -k1,1 {}) <(sort -k1,1 {}) > {}.ScoreProfile"
perf_join_cmd = perf_join_cmd.format(meta, extracted_snps, out)
os.system("bash -c '{}'".format(perf_join_cmd))
```

Note that the above won't work if `perf_join_cmd` contains any single quotes.
If that's a problem, you could try to enclose in double quotes instead.
(If `perf_join_cmd` doesn't contain double quotes...)

It's very fragile to run complex shell commands like this.
Users are very often confused about quoting and shell expansion rules when working in simple shell environments.
When doing that through another language,
it gets even more confusing and error-prone.

A good middle ground could be to encapsulate the complex command into a script, so that you can run simply:

```
os.system("script.sh args ...")
```

The `bash -c '...'` wrapping won't be necessary here,
the `script.sh` should have a correct `#!/bin/bash` shebang line,
and it will behave as expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
perf_join_cmd = "join <(sort -k1,1 {}) <(sort -k1,1 {}) > {}.ScoreProfile"
```

you probably just need to close the first `<`.

```
perf_join_cmd = "join <(sort -k1,1 {})> <(sort -k1,1 {}) > {}.ScoreProfile"
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. It seems like I need to use bash.