# Curly braces in os.system on python

Tags: python, bash, curly-braces

In the linux terminal i can delete all files from directory including hidden ones with:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder/{*,.*} 2> /dev/null
```

I'm trying to run the following command via os.system in python:

```py
>>> os.system('sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder/{*,.*}')
```

this will exit without any error (exit code 0) but do not delete nothing.

I understand here probably the curly braces have a special meaning but trying `\{*,.*\}` will not change nothing.

Wondering what going one here and how to tell python to use the Curly braces as in the terminal.

Of corse to make the job done i can do:

```py
os.system('sudo rm -r /path/to/folder/* /path/to/folder/.myHiddenFile')  # or other combination
```

But i want to understand how to play with the Curly braces here.

Comment: I suspect the braces are being expanded by the terminal itself *before* being passed to rm, while executing the command this way will pass them directly to rm.

Comment: interresting theorie...

Comment: @Kemp exactly that is the case

Comment: Related: [os.system() execute command under which linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/905221/4518341) General question: [How to execute a program or call a system command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/4518341)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.system` calls the C standard library function [`system`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system), which  executes the command with `/bin/sh -c`.

Since the curly brace expansion you are using is a bash feature, the underlying shell that `os.system` is using simply does not understand.

To workaround, you can explicitly execute the command in bash by invoking `/bin/bash` (or whereever your bash is) with the `-c` argument. E.g.

```
os.system("/bin/bash -c 'sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder/{*,.*}'")
```

NOTE: the use of single quotes, which are needed because of `sudo`.

Comment: OMG, why didn't I think of this ? +1 !

Comment: Yep this is great, work well and good explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`os` just helps you make a subset of OS-related system calls. The curly brace expansion you are describing is not an OS-related feature, it's a bash idiom. I doubt it is available even in other (non-bash) shells, as a rule.

The bash curly brace feature parses your curly brace expression and uses rules to turn it into more verbose expressions. You can read more about it [here](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/all-about-curly-braces-bash/) as well as other places on the internet if you google "bash curly braces".

If you want to do something similar to what bash curly braces do *on files*, check out the python library `glob`. If you want to do something similar to what bash curly braces do *on text* or *on numbers*, you can look at `itertools` maybe. (Or, in all these cases, maybe you really just want to write a simple for loop.)

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` does not do shell expansion. This means the curly braces are left as they are, and not replaced as you are used to it from in the terminal. To get this feature, you can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) with `shell=True`:

```py
import subprocess, shlex

result = subprocess.run(shlex.split("sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder/{*,.*}"), shell=True) # shlex.split converts the string into an argument list

print("rm exited with exit code %s, and printed following output\n%s\n and following errors\n%s\n" % (result.exitcode, result.stdout, result.stderr))
```